# Lambda used with different list elements

Tags: python, list, lambda, functional-programming

I am trying to implement a function by using the following example from [Replacements for switch statement in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python):

```
def f(x):
    return {
        '+': (lambda x: x[1] + x[2]),
        '-': (lambda x: x[1] - x[2])
    }[x[0]]

print(f(["+",2,3])) #Output should be 5. 

f(["-", 4, 1]) # Output should be 3.
```

I am clearly doing something wrong. Maybe someone has even a better suggestion for this?

**EDIT**:

What if I wanted to save the output of the lambda in a list and then return it?

For example:

```
def f(x, output):
    return {
        '+': (lambda x: x[1] + x[2]),
        '-': (lambda x: x[1] - x[2])
    }[x[0]]

output = [10, 20, 30, 40]

# to 2nd element in output list we add the last element in the list
print(f(["+",2,3], output)) #Output should be output = [10, 20, 33, 40]

output = [10, 20, 30, 40]
f(["-", 1, 100]) # Output should be [10, 120, 30, 40].
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember to actually *apply* the mapped function to the variable:

```
def f(x):
    return {
        '+': (lambda x: x[1] + x[2]),
        '-': (lambda x: x[1] - x[2])
    }[x[0]](x)

print(f(["+",2,3]))  # 5
```

---

This is a more flexible version:

```
d = {'+': (lambda x: x[1] + x[2]),
     '-': (lambda x: x[1] - x[2])}

def calculator(x, d):
    return d[x[0]](x)

print(calculator(["+",2,3], d))  # 5
```

---

An even better idea is to use your dispatcher to only store operations.

See [@WillemVanOnsem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49753237/9209546) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary maps a string to a *function*, not the result of that function, that is where the `lambda` comes in. You can solve it in two ways: or you calculate the results directly, or you call the function at the end.

```
def f(x):
    return {
        '+': (lambda: x[1] + x[2]),
        '-': (lambda: x[1] - x[2])
    }[x[0]]()  # calling the function!

print(f(["+",2,3])) #Output should be 5. 

f(["-", 4, 1]) # Output should be 3.
```

You can however also declare functions, and pass arguments to it. This will make it more flexible as well, since for instance a hypothetical `f(["sin", 1.2])` has only a single argument. We can for instance construct a dictionary like:

```
from operator import add, sub
from math import sin

FUNC_DICT = {
    '+': add,
    '-': sub,
    'sin': sin
}
```

Then our `f` looks like:

```
def f(x):
    return FUNC_DICT[x[0]](*x[1:])
```

So we call the function with the rest of the elements in the list.